# Angular 5 - update and forEach only on the first items

Tags: javascript, firebase, foreach, angular5, angularfire2

I'm trying to run two functions, `calculoDes()` and `desempenhos()`, in Angular 5, but weird behavior occurs as a result.

The first function performs a calculation on some phases, always generating an Array of objects for the next step. The steps are commented (maybe the problem is how I do this function, although it works):

```
calculoDes(){
      // each query item of 'ficha' creates a keyarray array and uses data to compute the quotient (quociente)
      this.fichas.subscribe(res => {
        res.forEach(item => {
          this.keyArray.push(item.$key);
          this.quocienteCidade = +(((item.cap_cilindrica/100)+(item.quant_marchas/2)+(item.largura/100)+(item.comprimento/1000)+(item.entre_eixos/1000)+(item.peso_seco/10))*-1).toFixed(5);
          this.desCidade.push({quociente: this.quocienteCidade, id: item.$key});
        });

        // The 'desCidade' object must be ordered by the quotient value, using the sortOn()
        this.sortOn(this.desCidade, "quociente");  

        // The 'range' is calculated by dividing 100 by the total amount of items
        this.range = 100/this.desCidade.length;

        / * Performance (desempenhoCidade) is calculated from an "equivalence" between each position in the array 'deCidade' and the percentage that it represents. The largest will always be 100. Stores on object 'desCidade2' * /
        for (var i = 0; i < this.desCidade.length; i++) {
          this.desempenhoCidade = +(100-((i+1)-1)*this.range).toFixed(1);
          this.desCidade2.push({desempenhoCid: this.desempenhoCidade});
        }

        //Merge between two Arrays: 'desCidade' e 'desCidade2'
        this.desCidade3 = _.merge(this.desCidade, _.map(this.desCidade2, this.getDesempenho));

        // Returns the previous sort, but with the already calculated performance
        this.resultCidade = this.sortTwo(this.desCidade3, this.keyArray, 'id');
        // retrieve only performance (desempenhoCid)
        this.resultCidade = this.resultCidade.map(a => a.desempenhoCid);    
      });
    }



  //sort using the $ key property, sortOn is for NEGATIVES, AS 'CIDADE'
   sortOn (arr, prop) {
     arr.sort ((a, b) => {
          if (a[prop] > b[prop]){
              return -1;
          } else if (a[prop] < b[prop]){
              return 1;
          } else {
          return 0;   
          }
        }
    );
  }

// order an array of objects in the order of an array
sortTwo (array, order, key) {
  array.sort ((a, b) => {
    var A = a[key], B = b[key];     
    if (order.indexOf(A) > order.indexOf(B)) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }       
  });  
  return array;
};

// Lodash to merge between two Arrays, including the property below
getDesempenho(el) { 
  return _.pick(el, 'desempenhoCid'); 
}
```

I call this function in `ngOnInit()` and the results are as expected.

From the results of this function, I need to use both arrays (`keyArray` and `resultCidade`) to update a data in `Firebase` (using `AngularFire`):

```
desempenhos(){
      this.keyArray.forEach(keyItem => {
        this.db.object('ficha/' + keyItem).update({
          // the item to be updated
          des_cidade: this.resultCidade[0]
        });
        // to each $key, I use the first position of the array and then I exclude it
        this.resultCidade.shift();
      })
    }
```

The problem is that this function only performs correctly on the first items, but then strangely returns to the function `calculoDes()` and becomes like a loop over loop (considering both functions!).

I have already searched it, I have redo it, but I could not find out where the error is between functions.